# C++ Xcode build failure, errno.h not fount

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, build-error

I am working on learning c++ and tried to build a simple hello world program in Xcode (MacOS Catalina). It is a Command line program. I followed the prompt on Xcode and accepted all the default parameters then created a cppfile with the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    std::cout<< "hello";
    return 0;
    
    
    
}
```

This doesn't compile and gives me a Lexical or Prepreocessor error:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/errno.h:31:15: 'errno.h' file not found

As well as two semantic errors:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:71:9: No member named 'strcpy' in the global namespace

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:73:9: No member named 'strcat' in the global namespace

From what I can tell these issues are linked to including IOStream. I don't understand why they are happening though I have written c++ using visual studio on a windows machine before and never had this issue. Ive never had so much difficulty with a hello world program before.

**EDIT**

I created a new project in Xcode and it worked in the new one. I am not sure what mistake I made the first time.

Comment: Did you upgrade XCode too?

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked for me (macOS 11.0.1, Xcode 12.2). If you don't get an answer, you might try navigating the path that the error is giving you to see if anything's missing or otherwise seems amiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My project was a framework instead of an Xcode project. I discovered this by looking under the products folder and seeing it was .framework instead of .app.

Comment: What do you mean by its a framework? I thought you can only do swift or objective-c framework now?